# How do I use an include statement in a TXT record?

Tags: domain-name-system, dkim, txt-record, tinydns, djbdns

We have a client that is using an email service that requires a TXT domain key reocrd that is over 127 characters long.  I'm pretty sure BIND allows this, however we run djbdns with tinydns and it looks as though it only supports txt records up to 127 characters.  And the rest is being truncated.  I was thinking I can do an include combining them, but I'm not really sure how.

I was thinking of setting the value to somthing like...

```
v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC2GWCNaDTuC3include:bdk2._domainkey.mail.cutlerymania.com
```

My thought is, will this grab the actual value located at that domain which only has one record which is a TXT record and simply append that information so the entire key record gets sent correctly?

Comment: SPF or DKIM?  That's a DKIM record you have there - if it needs to be SPF instead, then it'll probably be a whole lot shorter.

Comment: You're correct, I don't really do much DNS so this is all new to me.

Answer (score 0):

SPF and DKIM are both TXT RR

The text is enclosed in quotes. Multiple quoted strings may appear on a single line or parentheses may be used to contain them if they appear on multiple lines. In both cases the eclosed text (eliminating the quotes) is concatenated (joined) with no intervening characters added.

```
; multiple quoted strings on multiple lines
joe        IN      TXT    ("Located in a black hole" 
                           " somewhere over the rainbow")
; generates a single text string of 
; Located in a black hole somewhere over the rainbow
```

Comment: Thanks for the tidbit, but my question refers to the use of 'includes' to increase the size of a TXT record.  I'm not using bind so bind specific information isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: Include is SPF-specific, AFAIK. But you shown DKIM?

Answer (score 0):

For SPF you can use the syntax

```
v=spf1 a mx 1.2.3.4/24 2a00:1450:8007::63/48 include:otherdomain.com
```

If you have many records to include, you usually break them down by organization and then use one include: for each.